# Iterating through JSON is requiring more for loops than I'd like

Tags: python, refactoring

I am reading through a .json file and parsing some of the data to save into an Object. There are only 2000 or so items within the JSON that I need to iterate over, but the script I currently have running takes a lot longer than I'd like.

```
data_file = 'v1/data/data.json'
user = User.objects.get(username='lsv')
format = Format(format='Limited')
format.save()
lost_cards = []
lost_cards_file = 'v1/data/LostCards.txt'

with open(data_file) as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for item in data:
    if item['model'] == 'cards.cardmodel':
        if len(Card.objects.filter(name=item['fields']['name'])) == 0:
            print(f"card not found: {item['fields']['name']}")
            lost_cards.append(item['fields']['name'])
        try:
            Rating(
                card=Card.objects.get(name=item['fields']['name'], set__code=item['fields']['set']),
                rating=item['fields']['rating'],
                reason=item['fields']['reason'],
                format=format,
                rator=user
            ).save()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, item['fields']['name'], item['fields']['set'])
            break

with open(lost_cards_file, 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(lost_cards))
```

The code is working as expected, but it's taking a lot longer than I'd like. I'm hoping there is a built-in JSON or iterator function that could accelerate this process.

Answer (score 0):

There is. It's called the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

```py
with open(data_file, 'r') as input_file:
    dictionary_from_json = json.load(input_file)
```

should do it.